# Windows 10 update to 10586 fails with 0x8007070c

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, updates

I´m desperate as I couldn´t find a solution in other forums and I trust this one the most to find one.

I use a T420 with Windows 10 Home 64bit.
The build 10240 is still in use and since 6 months Windows asks me to update to 10586. It schedules automatic updates I can´t cancel and now I´m totally tired of it and want to solve this problem with help from others.

Note: I absolutely don´t want to make a clean install because I have a hell lot of stuff installed and configured.

The update fails every time. The Windows update message tells me directly after startup "Windows could not complete".
The routine tells me the error 0x8007070c which doesn´t appear to be thrown by anyone elses computer in the whole interwebz.

I tried several ways to achieve a successful update, those are:

1) I tried what "Likhitha V" wrote [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/unable-to-install-windows-10-home-version-1511/cacc1c01-f949-42d1-acb2-fc804b200658). Basically stopping the update service, change some files and start ist again.

2) Download the Media Creation Tool, load the .iso and Update with setup.exe. The update quits at ~92% with the very helpful message "There was a problem." and I´m back on the desktop.

3) I uninstalled AntiVirus software and quit all of my running 3rd party software via system tray and task manager and tried to update with the .iso, same problem as 2)

4) I ran sfc scannow, no issues detected.

Maybe there are people here knowing how to tackle this problem.

Thank you so much.

Comment: 0x8007070c = ERROR_INVALID_DATATYPE. Try the update (Build 14393) which will be released on 2nd August

Comment: Thanks andre, I just read the update announcement too :) Let´s see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to magicandre1981 I installed the Anniversary Update manually and it ran through with the first try.

Steps to do it:

1. Go to Windows Updates via typing "Search for updates" in win menu
2. Click on "learn more", a Microsoft website will open
3. On the website you can download the Anniversary Update installer
4. Launch the installer, wait and enjoy